# Assigning None if value does not exist

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's assume we have a dictionary with two keys and known values:

```
dictionary = {'first_name': 'Jennifer', 'last_name': 'Lawrence'}
```

However, since I retrieve the information from an API that cannot guarantee that all keys are returned, I have to test whether the keys exist.

If I want to assign the value of this key `"first_name"` to the variable new_object, I intended to use the following expression:

```
new_object = dictionary['first_name'] **or None**
```

However, if the key `'first_name'` is not in the dictionary, I receive a key error. Apparently, it seems that I cannot use Swift's principle of optionals here.

Does Python support any kind of inline test to verify that a variable exists/is declared, and if it doesn't instead assigns the value None to the new variable? In the case above, with a dictionary with only the key `'last_name'` would, therefore, result in the assignment of the value `None` to `new_object`.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries have a method `.get()` for this:

```
new_object = dictionary.get('first_name')
```

It takes a key and returns either the value (if set) or a default value (which unless otherwise specified is `None`).